# Where are all of the cog tags in Gears of War Judgement ?

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

There are 42 cog tags to be recovered in Judgement.   Where are they all located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a video walkthrough with all the cog tag locations:

^ the video above assumes familiarity with the levels in GoW: Judgement

If you need a more in-depth walkthrough, then maybe try this video: